# How to change the increment value for skip in DevExtreme custom store pagination for a dxList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

I'm working with DevExtreme and have implemented a custom store for paginating a list. The `skip` value in my custom store currently increments by 20, and the default `take` value is 20. However, I want to change the increment value to be different (for example, increment by 10 instead of 20).

Here's the relevant part of my script.js:

```
// Configuring API URL
const apiUrl = 'https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds';

// Function to load data using Custom Store
const loadDataSource = (loadOptions) => {
    const { skip, take } = loadOptions;

    console.log({ skip, take });

    const params = {
        page: Math.floor(skip / take) + 1,
        limit: take,
    };

    console.log(params);

    return fetch(`${apiUrl}?page=${params.page}&limit=${params.limit}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => ({
            data: result,
            totalCount: result.length,
        }));
};

// Creating a Custom Store for pagination and data loading
const customStore = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
    load: loadDataSource,
});

const dxList = $('#data-grid').dxList({
    dataSource: customStore,
    itemTemplate(data) {
        return $('<div>')
            .append($('<div>').text(data.name))
            .append($('<div>').text(data.id))
            .append($('<div>').text(data.temperament))
    },
    showSelectionControls: true,
    pageLoadMode: 'scrollBottom',
    height: 600,
    paginate: true,
    pageSize: 10, // I tried adjusting this, but it's not working
});
```

I've attempted to modify the `pageSize` option, but it doesn't seem to affect the increment value of `skip`. How can I achieve the desired behavior of changing the increment value for `skip` in the pagination process?
Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!